# Failed to query Elasticsearch using : TransportErrorr(400, 'parsing_exception')

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-cms

I have been trying to get the Elasticsearch to work in a Django application. It has been a problem because of the mess of compatibility considerations this apparently involves. I follow the recommendations, but still get an error when I actually perform a search.

Here is what I have

```
Django==2.1.7
Django-Haystack==2.5.1
Elasticsearch(django)==1.7.0
Elasticsearch(Linux app)==5.0.1
```

There is also `DjangoCMS==3.7` and `aldryn-search=1.0.1`, but I am not sure how relevant those are.

Here is the error I get when I submit a search query via the basic text form.

```
GET /videos/modelresult/_search?_source=true [status:400 request:0.001s]
Failed to query Elasticsearch using '(video)': TransportError(400, 'parsing_exception')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/user-name/miniconda3/envs/project-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/haystack/backends/elasticsearch_backend.py", line 524, in search
_source=True)
File "/home/user-name/miniconda3/envs/project-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 69, in _wrapped
return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
File "/home/user-name/miniconda3/envs/project-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py", line 527, in search
doc_type, '_search'), params=params, body=body)
File "/home/user-name/miniconda3/envs/project-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 307, in perform_request
status, headers, data = connection.perform_request(method, url, params, body, ignore=ignore, timeout=timeout)
File "/home/user-name/miniconda3/envs/project-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 93, in perform_request
self._raise_error(response.status, raw_data)
File "/home/user-name/miniconda3/envs/project-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/base.py", line 105, in _raise_error
raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(status_code, error_message, additional_info)
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: TransportError(400, 'parsing_exception')
```

Could someone tell me if this is an issue with compatibility or is there something else going on? How can I fix it?

Comment: Please add the query for which you are getting this error.

Comment: It is tough to know. I am not writing any queries. My understanding is that the apps listed above do it on the back-end.

Answer (score 1):

The combination that appears to have worked for my setup is as follows. I believe the key was to drastically downgrade the Elasticsearch.

```
Elasticsearch=1.7.6 (with Java 8)
Django==2.1.7
Django-Haystack==2.8.1
elasticsearch==1.7.0
```

The two items below may or may not be relevant. I have not changed them.

```
DjangoCMS==3.7.0
aldryn-search==1.0.1
```